# Blazor MSAL Error AADSTS50058. A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-msal, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor WASM app that is configured to use MSAL authentication.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("profile");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("{{ MY SCOPE }}");
    
    options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";      
});
```

I can then inject an `ITokenProvider` to get an Access token that I can append to my `HttpCLient` request.

```
var tokenGetter = await tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();

if (tokenGetter.TryGetToken(out var token))
{
     if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.Value))
     {
         //Token available here        
     }
}
```

The problem is, when I navigate to an `[Authorize]` restricted page, I get the following errors.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
> (Bad Request) login.microsoftonline.oauth2/v2.0/token

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: login_required: AADSTS50058:
> A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.

Everything was working before, so I suspect that my token has expired, and it needs to be refreshed. I am not sure where I can detect this. Is there somewhere that I can catch this exception, and then redirect the user back to the login page?

Everything works if I don't specify a cache location, but I don't want to use session cache for this app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [BlazorWasm templates](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-app-template#use-of-the-blazor-web-assembly-template) ? That should help get you started.
Info on [web apps](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apps#why-to-use-microsoftidentityweb-in-web-apps).
Info on [handling conditional access](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access#in-blazor-server).